# Straight line through $(a,b)$ with slope $m$ is the graph of the function $f(x) = m(x-a) + b$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

Spivak's Calculus Chapter 3 Problem 6 says:

> Show that the straight line through $(a,b)$ with slope $m$ is the graph of the function $f(x) = m(x-a) + b$.

Since the slope in a graph of a line is determined by using similar triangles, or taking the change in $y$ and dividing it by the change in $x$, slope $m = {\Delta{y}\over\Delta{x}}$ and I used the points $(x,f(x))$ and $(a, f(a))$ where x is an unknown x-coordinate.

That would mean that $m = {f(x)-f(a)\over{x-a}}$. Multiplying both sides by $x-a$ assuming that the points have distinct x-coordinates (is this allowed?), I get $m(x-a) = f(x)-f(a)$ and adding $f(a)$ to both sides, we get $f(x) = m(x-a) + f(a)$. The book says that the straight line goes through $(a,b)$ so $f(a) = b$.

Therefore, $f(x) = m(x-a) + b$ which is the point-slope equation which is what we want and this shows that a graph of a line going through the point $(a,b)$ with slope $m$ has the equation $f(x) = m(x-a) + b$.

Is this proof valid? If not, can somebody give me hints because this is all I can think of.

Comment: Hi, please use the title of your question to describe exactly what you're asking--I edited this time to illustrate what a good title is. Also, please only use the `self-learning` tag for questions about the *process* of self-learning, not mathematical questions you encountered while self-learning.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is fine. You can purposely choose to restrict $x \ne a$ because that is all you actually need, since you can figure out $f(a)$ by the other part that you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the proof is fine.  It's one of those annoying ones where you're trying to prove the thing is what you want it to be because it really couldn't work any other way, so it's easy to fall into circularity.

Here's my quibble:

By defining the slope $m$ in terms of $(x,f(x))$, as you do in your second paragraph, this assumes that $f$ maps points on the line you want...which is what we're trying to prove.  In other words, you've shown that $f$ is *a* line with slope $m$ that goes through $(a,b)$, but you haven't established that this is *the same line* as the one derived from the scaling of similar triangles.

But since there really is only the one line that does this (at least in the Euclidean plane...non-Euc may be different, which is why things like this are actually non-trivial, I think...), it's hard to catch this kind of subtlety.  I'm still not 100% convinced with my argument, but I think it makes sense.  [Comments or criticisms, please!]

What you want to do to avoid this is find another point on a triangle scaled up or down by a constant $c$.  WLOG, we can assume the right triangle has one vertex at $(0,0)$ so two points on the line we want are $(a,b)$ and $(ca, cb)$.

You then define $m$ as the ratio of these x-y differences and show that $f$ gives you $cb$ when you input $ca$ for all $c$. In other words, we get the value of the slope $m$ $\underline{without}$ relying on inputs/outputs of $f$, and then show that any input into $f$ gives us the output that is on the scaled triangle line.